# NoMethodError in Places#Show (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I'm trying to create the ability for users to add comments and upload photos  to their pages, but I keep getting this NoMethodError in Places#show error. It says the following (and I'm quoting the error page):

```
undefined method `place_photos_path' for #<#<Class:0xb5d58300>:0xb5642930>
```

And then shows me the line of code where the issue is apparently located:

```
  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add a comment</h4>
          </div>

        <%= simple_form_for @photo, :url => place_photos_path(@place) do |f| %>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <%= f.input :caption %>
         </div>
```

It highlights the **simple_form** line as being the line in question. I'm really stuck. Any help would be so much appreciated.

Here is the config/routes.rb file:

```
Findmygirlfriend::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'places#index'
  resources :places do
    resources :comments, :only => :create
  end
  resources :users, :only => :show
  resources :photos, :only => :create
end
```

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Please show us your `config/routes.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Just place your resources at the right scope. This should help

```
Findmygirlfriend::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  root 'places#index'
  resources :places do
    resources :comments, :only => :create
    resources :photos, :only => :create
  end
  resources :users, :only => :show
end
```

Comment: Now I'm getting another error. It's a NoMethodsError in Places#Index. The line is the "My Profile" line. Forgive me, I tried formatting and couldn't get it to work. 
 
            –</ul>
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

         <% if user_signed_in? %>
           <li><%= link_to 'My Profile', user_path(current_user) %></li>
           <li><%= link_to 'Sign out, dude', destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete %></li>
           <% else %>
           <li>–

Comment: I think something is going on with the places#index page. It's not recognizing a method that I added. Somewhere along the way, my pipeline  is not connected.

Comment: Nevermind! That comment above works! Thank you so much, Asiniy! You're the best! *hugs!*